# The requested URL was not found on this server in virtualhost of apache

Tags: apache

Help! I setup two virtual hosts in apache2, but one is work and another is error

May I know how to change will let two virtual hosts can work?

The detail setup like as below:

www1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    
    DocumentRoot "/var/www1"
    
    Alias /www1/ "/var/www1/"
    <Directory /var/www1>
    Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

www2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    DocumentRoot "/var/www2"
    
    Alias /www2/ "/var/www2/"
    <Directory /var/www2>
    Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

$ apache2ctl -S

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www1.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www1.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www2.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page Title</title>
    <!--- Head HTML goes here -->
    <!--- Link to styles in CSS tab -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--- Paste HTML below here -->
    <h3> Test Page </h3> 
    <!--- Link to code in JavaScript tab -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I enable two config www1.conf and www2.conf. Then use the browser test two url like as below.

Output result:

```
192.168.xx.xx is one ip address

http://192.168.xx.xx/www1/index.html
work well

http://192.168.xx.xx/www2/index.html
error message:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

How can I use two alias in the one ip address host?